# Incorrect format in cumulative sum of time column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that allows me to view a running total of a certain time column in my database, by using a user-defined variable:

```
SET @total_duration := '00:00:00';
SELECT duration, (@total_duration := @total_duration + duration) AS cumulative_duration
FROM tbl_flights
```

However, the results appear like this:

[image]

I'm pretty sure the running total is correct, but that it just needs formatting to appear like `hh:mm:ss`. I'm not sure how to do this, if anyone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `time_to_sec` and `sec_to_time` functions:

The `order by` is required to get consistent results. Assuming you want to find this cumulative sum in the increasing order of one or more columns , say `flight_id`:

```
SET @total_duration := 0;
SELECT 
    duration,
    sec_to_time(@total_duration := @total_duration
                 + time_to_sec(duration)) AS cumulative_duration
FROM tbl_flights
ORDER BY flight_id -- required to get consistent results
                   -- (change the column name in "order by" as needed.)
```

Comment: Works perfect now, thank you. Will mark as correct when it lets me.

Comment: you need `order by` for this query to produce consistent results.